# IE8 does not print an image in :before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to put an icon image before a text. Any HTML tag such as <img> should be avoided because any changes of HTML structure may affect our javascript code.

I write the following code and it works on screen with IE8/Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8' />
  <style type="text/css">
  div.before-test:before {
    content: url("sample.png");
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>bbbb</div>
<div class="before-test">cccc</div>
<div>dddd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, when visitors try to print the web page with IE8, the image disappears. How can I show the image even when printing with IE8, or must I add HTML tag for the image?

Comment: I see the same behavior. IE9 is fine, but IE8 doesn't show the image for printing.

Comment: Thanks. I will put an <img> tag instead of :before pseudo element for printing.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 supports before but not in compatibility mode.

Comment: I know it, and I change the compatibility mode with "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8' />". ":before" works well with IE8 on screen, but not on printing.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should look at this guide as to what properties and stuff are supported on some browsers especially IE 6 and up.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

by the way, the url in `url()` - quotes are optional. better to have none to avoid unnecessary escaping issues

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.before-test:before {
        content: url(sample.png);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is about printing. Do you know any sites which describe what CSS we can use for printing?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could find is from in stackoverflow. I know, it is not a good approach but , i guess there is no solution about this bug

HTML:

```
<div class="PrintOnly">
  <img id="PrintLogo" src="sample.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .PrintOnly {         display:none; } 
   @media print {  
      .PrintOnly {     display:block; }
   }
```